# How to get route id / flow id of a vehicle in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

omnet++ veins module have a function `getRoadId()` that returns current "road id" of vehicles but how can I have "route id" or "flow id" of a vehicle.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I am sorry for that question, actually I was using veins-3.0 previously. In veins-3.0 there was no such function.

Today I have migrated to veins-4a2. Here it can be easily found by using `traciVehicle->getRouteId()`. Many thanks to Sir. Christoph Sommer for this update.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Veins 2.0-rc1, even if such function is not implemented, you can easily implement it, by creating a new function that do the job under the **TraCIScenarioManager** class.

In order to do it, you have to check functions implemented under this class, along to a good reading/understanding of TraCI Python module already documented under SUMO.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to use it in an older version of veins is possible to add it manually as it follows:

In **TraCICommandInterface.h** write the `std::string getRoadId();` definition:

```
// Vehicle methods
        bool addVehicle(std::string vehicleId, std::string vehicleTypeId, std::string routeId, simtime_t emitTime_st = -DEPART_NOW, double emitPosition = -DEPART_POS_BASE, double emitSpeed = -DEPART_SPEED_MAX, int8_t emitLane = -DEPART_LANE_BEST_FREE);

    class Vehicle {
        public:
            Vehicle(TraCICommandInterface* traci, std::string nodeId) : traci(traci), nodeId(nodeId) {
                connection = &traci->connection;
            }

            ...
            std::string getRoadId(); //here is the definition
            ...

        protected:
            TraCICommandInterface* traci;
            TraCIConnection* connection;
            std::string nodeId;
    };

    Vehicle vehicle(std::string nodeId) {
        return Vehicle(this, nodeId);
    }
```

In **TraCICommandInterface.cc** write the `std::string getRoadId();` declaration:

```
std::string TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::getRoadId() {
return traci->genericGetString(CMD_GET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, nodeId, VAR_ROAD_ID, RESPONSE_GET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method gets a list with the vehicle's route:

```
traciVehicle->getPlannedRoadIds();
```